# ng-repeat not growing with object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm doing this:

```
<body>
    <div ng-controller="PresentationCtrl">
        <a href="" ng-click="findAll()">Find</a>
        <div>
            <ul class ="unstyled">
                <li ng-repeat="p in presentations">
                    <img ng-src="{{p}}" alt="presentation">
                </li> 
            </ul>
        <div>
    </div>
</body>
```

I have one placeholder element inside of `presentations`  that is set when the function `PresentationCtrl` is hit.

When the `findAll` link is hit, I add an element to the array like so: `$scope.presentations.push(sUrl);`

But, when viewing my page, the list doesn't grow.

Does `ng-repeat` only fire once, or something? Can I force it to "refresh" and display the current values in `presentations`?

Here's my controller

The `console.log` before I push the element into the array gets hit. and displays the string that I expect.

```
function PresentationCtrl($scope){
$scope.presentations = ["http://angularjs.org/img/AngularJS-small.png"];

$scope.findAll = function(){
    var socket=null;
    socket = io.connect('http://[server]:3000');
    socket.on('handshake',function(){
        socket.emit('viewAll',{tenant:'qa'});
        socket.on('returnAll',function(back){
            for(i=0;i<back.length;i++){
                for(j=0;j<back[i].slides.length;j++){
                    socket.emit('signUrl',(back[i].slides[j].location));
                    break;
                }
            }
            socket.on('signedUrls',function(sUrl){
                console.log("back from signedUrls" + sUrl);
                $scope.presentations.push(sUrl);
            });
        });
    });
};
}
```

Comment: Can we see your `PresentationCtrl` controller

Comment: Yeah we really need to see the controller to help.

Comment: Are you sure u r seeing this in console? "back from signedUrls" ...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it works fine.

http://plnkr.co/edit/agadSBFgz8YhWuDTtCPx?p=preview

Your situation might be different.

--------- EDIT ---------

ok, I got your situation. You are running a function not under watch of AngularJS.
Thus, AngularJS does not know that your variable is changed, basically $digest is not called.

To mimic native Javascript asynchronous call, I use setTimeout.

The following code **does not** work. It change the value, but it won't be watched.

```
setTimeout( function() {
  $scope.presentations = [6,7,8,9];
}, 1000);
```

However this code **does** work. It change the value as expected

```
$timeout( function() {
  $scope.presentations = [6,7,8,9];
}, 1000);
```

The difference between setTimeout and $timeout is that $timeout is running under watch of AngularJS.
Thus to make it work, you need to run `$scope.apply()` after it, or within it as a function.

This code **does** work with `setTimeout`.

```
setTimeout( function() {
  $scope.presentations = [6,7,8,9];
  $scope.$apply();
}, 1000);
```

Can't explain all to you in detail because I don't really mastered the AngularJS code.

This blog has a very good explanation about why we need to run $apply.

http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html

Just for the tip, to get the answer quickly, it's better to have a simplified example in jsfiddle or plunkr.
I know $http call cannot be demoed in plunkr or jsfiddle, but you can mimic your situation using `setTimeout`. It can make your situation understandable to readers most of time.

Comment: I had the same problem with a datatables.net xhr.dt event not refreshing the grid.