# Async $scope primative update from controller not appearing in view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-binding, asynchronous, controller

Why doesn't this code work? I am assigning a value to the $scope, when the page renders, I see 5 but once the timer fires, the value isn't updated. I am wondering what kind of object the primitive 5 needs to become so that Angular will watch it for changes. Also, if there is a proper way to do this kind of thing it would be nice to know.

```
app.controller('Total', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.total = 5;
    setTimeout(function() {
      $scope.total = 1300;
    }, 3000);
  }
]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that Angular didn't know I assigned a new value to $scope.total, [see the StackOverflow answer for more information on how binding works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9682092/databinding-in-angularjs/9693933#9693933). The solution is to use $scope.$apply and wrap the assignment in a function. Angular will then compare the previous value to the new value to fire the correct functions, [see an explanation with sample code of $scope.$apply here](http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html).

Solution:

```
app.controller('Total', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.total = 5;
    setTimeout(function() {
      $scope.$apply(function() {
        $scope.total = 1300;
      });
    }, 3000);
  }
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

use $timeout, then you don't need to use $apply.

Different question, but the same answer here, [ng-repeat not growing with object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21198250/ng-repeat-not-growing-with-object/21199245#21199245)

Comment: This solution is the correct choice to do what I was attempting but didn't help me understand my problem better. Thanks for the reply!